# Навигация через SegmentedControl при AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, navigationcontroller

Добрый день!

Как правильно расположить элементы во `ViewController`, чтобы при переключении `SegmentedControll` менялось содержимое во второй нижней его половине?

Как это реализовать при `autolayout`?

Спасибо!

Ps. Очень схож интерфейс с Instagram (первая и вторая вкладки). На Андроиде получилось с помощью TabHost, а тут совсем туго...
Или может это совсем по-другому реализуется и проще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 вариант:** когда переключаете в SegmentControll, то прячьте ненужные view и показывайте нужное:

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender {
  UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
  NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

  if (selectedSegment == 0) {
    // Когда нажали первый сегмент
    [firstView setHidden:NO];
    [secondView setHidden:YES];
  }
  else{
    //Когда нажали второй сегмент
    [firstView setHidden:YES];
    [secondView setHidden:NO];
  }
}
```

**2 вариант:** тот же самый, что и первый, но только использовать анимации (типа листание между view):

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    NSInteger selectedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    if (selectedSegment == 0) {
        //Когда нажали первый сегмент
        firstView.frame = centerRect;
        secondView.frame = rightRect;
    }
    else{
        //Когда нажали второй сегмент
        firstView.frame = leftRect;
        secondView.frame = centerRect;
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**3 вариант:** это переключение между контроллерами https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110985/3868736 :

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
        [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        self.currentViewController = vc;
    }];
    self.navigationItem.title = vc.title;
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    UIViewController *vc;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FooViewController"];
            break;
        case 1:
            vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BarViewController"];
            break;
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Так же можете посмотреть похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views

Удачи Вам!

Comment: Спасибо! На днях буду разбираться - отпишусь обязательно тут!

Comment: Вообщем, все оказалось проще чем думал. Добавляем нижние View одну на другую и через сегмент просто напросто показываем одну из них, при этом скрывая остальные.

Comment: @Chekist как я и написал в первом варианте. Это самый простой вариант был.

Comment: Забыл отметить как правильный. Исправил ситуацию! Спасибо!